# Where is Amazon Linux AMI Test Page EC2?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have set up my websites as directories directly under `/var/www/html/` and they are working just fine (the websites are mapped to virtual hosts). So, this is mainly out of curiosity for the moment.

Furthermore, being able to customise this might bring some benefits in the future e.g. branding the elastic IPs my computer use temporarily.

Notes

- I can always create a `index.html` page under `/var/www/html/` and modify it but that's not my goal here.
- I can also map the elastic IP address to a directory `/var/www/html/default/` and do my    stuffs there but that is not also my goal here
- My goal is the find the Amazon Linux AMI test page
- I've tried running Linux command to find it but it takes too long obviously

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's actually an error page, and gets served because `index.html` is missing. You should find it somewhere in the vicinity of

```
/var/www/error/noindex.html
```

Comment: Thanks! That was quite silly of me, I should have narrowed my search to just `/var/www/` and I should then be able to find it immediately not to mentioned the clue given in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf` :D